# Django - JSON response with serialized object

Tags: ajax, django, json, serialization

I am trying to send a serialized object using JSON. Here is my view code:

```
if request.is_ajax():
        resp = {}
        if request.POST:
            if form.is_valid():
                g = form.save()
                resp['graph'] = serializers.serialize('json', [g, ])
                resp['success'] = True
            else:
                resp['errors'] = form.errors
                resp['success'] = False
            return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(resp), mimetype='application/javascript')
        return render(request, 'graph/inlines/create.html', {'form':form})
```

The problem is (rather obviously) that the 'graph' object I am trying to return is being serialized twice (once with serializers.serialize and again when I used simplejson.dumps) and the object is being received as a json string.

I tried just doing this:

```
resp['graph'] = g
```

But it throws a server error as the object obviously isn't serialized when I try to use simplejson.dumps.

Is there a way I can tell it to ignore this key when dumping the data? Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than serializing the graph queryset to json the first time, use `serializers.serialize('python',  g)` to convert it to a Python dictionary first. Then the whole thing will be converted to json at the end.

Comment: "Doesn't seem to"? What happens?

Comment: You didn't make clear that `g` is a single instance rather than a queryset. You could wrap it in a list, as you do in the original code.